# Beginner - TypeError in Python .sort()

Tags: python, excel, typeerror

I am going to sort the data by reading from Excel file in Python.

However, I've got some error and below is my code.

```
 mp_list = []
 for i in range(2, maxRow_input+1):
    mp=sheet_input.cell(i,mp_index).value
    mp_list.append(mp)
 mp_list.sort()
 print(mp_list)
```

This is what i've got an error message:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-110-9af441d1bedd> in <module>
      3     mp=sheet_input.cell(i,mp_index).value
      4     mp_list.append(mp)
  ----> 5 mp_list.sort()
      6 print(mp_list)

 TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Could anyone help me with this issue and please kindly explain me :)

Comment: seems some element in the list is string. Can you `print(mp_list)` ?

Comment: WOWWWW ! Thank you so much ! there's string in that column ! and I could fix it :D Thank you x 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the values in that excel column has same data type. It seems like the column is having different data type and hence the sort is giving error.